# Can I disable Pam Loginuid? Can I find out options used to configure kernel?

Tags: linux, security, configuration, kernel, pam

I am getting a lot of the following types of error in my secure log on a CentOS 5.4 server:

```
crond[10445]: pam_loginuid(crond:session): set_loginuid failed opening loginuid
sshd[10473]: pam_loginuid(sshd:session): set_loginuid failed opening loginuid
```

I've seen discussion of this being caused when using a non-standard kernel without the correct CONFIG_AUDIT and CONFIG_AUDITSYSCALL options set.  Where this is the case, it is advised to comment out some lines in the pam.d config files.

I am running a Virtual Private Server where I need to use the kernel provided by the supplier.  Is there a way to find out what options they used to configure the kernel?  I want to verify if the above is the cause.

If this turns out not to be the cause, what are the risk of disabling pam_loginuid for crond and sshd?

Comment: I found that the kernel had not been correctly configured - so commented out the required pam_loginuid for everything in /etc/pam.d that was requiring it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

config file for kernel on RHEL systems is stored in the /boot directory.  Searching in here I found that both settings had not been set.

Answer (score 1):

The current running kernel should have the configuration used to build it in /proc/config.gz

Comment: ls: /proc/config.gz: No such file or directory